# Running Interop COM in sharepoing 2010

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, com

I have a Com Component DLL which i register in SysWOW64 using `Regsvr32.exe`

I made a sample Windows Application to check the functionality of the component and it worked great i just had to change the platform target to x86 cause if i choose any CPU or x64 it throw this exception:

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00853A19-BD51-419B-9269-2DABE57EB61F} failed due to the following error: 80040154.
```

any way that wasn't a problem for me as i changed the target platform to x86, but the problem arise when i integrated that DLL with SharePoint 2010 ,cause as you guys know SharePoint must run in x64 platform context so the same exception thrown again, i don't know how to fix that so i got back to my sample application and changed the platform target to x64 to try to produce the same problem and now im trying to find another way to fix it without changing the platform target to x86

any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This Fixed it!](http://blogs.technet.com/b/meamcs/archive/2012/03/05/referencing-32-bit-com-components-in-sharepoint-2010-after-upgrade-from-sharepoint-2007.aspx)